# Partial sum estimate of sum of reciprocals of prime powers

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I want to estimate the following sum
$$
\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{{p^n}}\tag{1}
$$

Here n=2,3...

We already know by Mertens theorem:

$$\sum_{ p \text{ prime,} p \leq k } 1/p  - \log{\log{k}} = B + E(k) \tag{2}$$

Here $E(k)=o(1)$

B is constant which has an explicit expression

I'm wondering if the sum (1) has similar expression as sum (2) particularly with the explicitly expressable constant ?

Comment: Well, of course, your sums converge. So there is some $B_n$ such that $$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p^n}=B_n+o(1).$$ This is true for $n>1$ real, in fact.

Comment: Martens’ constant is represented as an infinite sum, as are the $B_n,$ so it seems like the $B_n$ are as explicit as Meetens’.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think that the sum is taken over all prime powers (except the primes). Doesn't this sum still converge ?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I suppose that is one way of reading it, although the wording is very unclear, with $n$ specified outside the sum notation. If OP wanted that interpretation, it should have been something like $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{p<\sqrt[n]x}\frac1{p^n}$$ @Peter

Comment: And I suspect you are correct that the larger sum also converges, but I haven’t come up with an obvious proof. @Peter

Comment: Well, isn't the sum just the sum of $\frac{1}{p(p-1)}$ , running over the primes ? By the way, my first impression was that the sum would diverge :)

Comment: Yes. @Peter $$\begin{align} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{p<x}\frac{1}{p^n}&=\sum_{p<x}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac1{p^n}\\&=\sum_{p<x}\frac{1}{p^2}\frac{1}{1-1/p}\\&=\sum_{p<x}\frac1{p(p-1)}<1 \end{align} $$ The last because $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac1{n(n-1)}=1.$